# CSS - ¿Cómo colocar un minititle sobre el content?

Tags: css, css3

Tengo un botón y dentro de él quisiera colocar el `minititle` sobre el `content` tal y como aparece en la siguiente imágen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pensé en usar `position:absolute` pero al hacer scroll actua como si fuere `position:fixed`

¿Cómo colocar un `minititle` sobre el `content` de forma tal que al hacer scroll no actue como `position:fixed`?

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir el código que genera el contenido similar a la imagen?

Comment: Es preferible que proporciones un  [**Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable**](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), de lo contrario estás esperando que codifiquemos desde cero. StackOverflow es un servicio para ayudar no para codificar por ti. Debes proporcionar lo que has intentado en código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al "minititle" ponle absolute pero al "content" debes ponerle posicionamiento relativo.

```
.content{
    position: relative;
}
.minititle{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Te falta agregarle `position: relative` al contenedor del elemento que quieres fijar.

```css
.container {
  height: 1000px;  
}

.content {
  background-color: red;
  border: solid 2px;
  font-size: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
}

.content > div {
  background-color: blue;
  border: solid 2px;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div>Minititle</div>
    CONTENT
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Intentando.....

Comment: ¿Funcionó o no?